# Instantiation of com.google.android.gms.location.LocationClient hangs

Tags: android, google-play-services, android-library, location-client

I am developping an android-library project with Android Studio that uses the google-play-services to make use of the Geofences API.

To include the Play Services, I use maven (build rule in the gradle.build file) exactly like the official Android documentation shows (http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html#Setup). In this android-library, I verify that the Google Play Services are available with the method `GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable` before instantiating a `LocationClient`.

```
Log.d(TAG, "Registering geofences");
try{
    if(GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this) != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS){
        Log.e(TAG, "Google Play Services unavailable");
        return;
    }else
        Log.d(TAG, "Google Play Services are available");
    Log.d(TAG, "creating LocationClient");
    locationClient = new LocationClient(context, this, this);
    Log.d(TAG, "connecting LocationClient");
    locationClient.connect();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Here is the log I get from Logcat :

```
04-11 09:45:27.331  23741-23781/foo.bar.myoldapp D/AWRLocationService﹕ Registering geofences
04-11 09:45:27.331  23741-23781/foo.bar.myoldapp W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve static field 3086 (common_google_play_services_install_title) in Lcom/google/android/gms/R$string;
04-11 09:45:27.331  23741-23781/foo.bar.myoldapp D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x60 at 0x004b
{... and around 20 similar lines ...}
04-11 09:45:27.341  23741-23781/foo.bar.myoldapp E/GooglePlayServicesUtil﹕ The Google Play services resources were not found. Check your project configuration to ensure that the resources are included.
04-11 09:45:27.351  23741-23781/foo.bar.myoldapp D/AWRLocationService﹕ Google Play Services are available
04-11 09:45:27.351  23741-23781/foo.bar.myoldapp D/AWRGeofencesReceiver﹕ creating LocationClient
04-11 09:45:27.351  23741-23781/foo.bar.myoldapp W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve static field 3100 (location_client_powered_by_google) in Lcom/google/android/gms/R$string;
04-11 09:45:27.351  23741-23781/foo.bar.myoldapp D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x60 at 0x0019
04-11 09:45:30.731  23741-23741/foo.bar.myoldapp D/AWRWifiScanResultBroadcastReceiver﹕ onReceive
```

As you can see, the Google Play services seem to not be perfectly included for a reason that is unknown to me (as I include them the way Google ask me to). But they seem to be present though, since `GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable` returns true. Then, I instantiate the LocationClient and nothing happens. No exception is thrown, and no error log are shown. What did I do wrong?